# Calling a variable from outside the function does not work javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

can anyone help ,,

so i have stored login data in a local storage key called login using @ngx-pwa

here i'm trying to get this data and display it but i'm getting undefined!

```
public customerProfile

ngOnInit() {
 this.getProfileData();
 console.log(this.cutomerProfile) //shows undefined
}

getProfileData() {
 this.localStorage.getItem('login').subscribe((login) => {
   this.customerProfile = login;
   console.log(this.customerProfile.user) //shows login data
 })
}
```

Comment: That;s because `getItem` is async, so `ngOnInit` is trying to print `customerProfile` before it's been set.

Comment: so should i use afterViewInit() {} or what should I do to get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest solution to log the value of customerProfile is to call a function that log that variable from the this.localStorage.getItem() which is async, so after it gets the stored item, it calls that callback function like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.getProfileData();
}

getProfileData() {
 this.localStorage.getItem('login').subscribe((login) => {
   this.customerProfile = login;
   console.log(this.customerProfile.user) ;
   callback();
 })
}

callback(){
    console.log(this.cutomerProfile);
}
```

Comment: AAAAaaaa l 7alawaaaa diiii :'D

Comment: you're welcome, sir

Answer (score 5):

The Problem is, that at the moment you call your `console.log()` at `ngOnInit()` `this.cutomerProfile` is not set, because `this.localStorage.getItem('login')` isn't ready.

Using a callback could be a solution for you:

```
public customerProfile

ngOnInit() {
 this.getProfileData(() => console.log(this.cutomerProfile));
}

getProfileData(cb) {
 this.localStorage.getItem('login').subscribe((login) => {
   this.customerProfile = login;
   console.log(this.customerProfile.user) //shows login data
   cb();
 })
}
```

you could use a promise, too:

```
public customerProfile

ngOnInit() {
 this.getProfileData().then(() => console.log(this.cutomerProfile));
}

getProfileData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.localStorage.getItem('login').subscribe((login) => {
      this.customerProfile = login;
      console.log(this.customerProfile.user) //shows login data
      resolve();
    })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want that you can by using `Promise` and `async/await` function.

```
public customerProfile;

async ngOnInit() {
 this.customerProfile = await this.getProfileData();
  // The console.log (next line) will wait for the promise to be resolved.
  console.log(this.customerProfile);     }

getProfileData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.localStorage.getItem('login').subscribe((login) => {
      resolve(login);
    })
  });
}
```